# How to overcome inconsistency while removing hyphen between words in a list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, list

I am using two sets of code to evaluate which is better in removing hyphen between words in a list.

First set of code

```
listnew=['E-Textbooks']
nounbreak= '-'.join(listnew).split('-')
```

The output of above is

```
['E', 'Textbooks']
```

In the second set, the code is as below

```
listnew=['E-Textbooks']
nounbreak= [" ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])", i)) for i in listnew]
```

The output for above is

```
['E Textbooks']
```

My problem is In the second set the output is ['E Textbooks'] while in the first it is ['E', 'Textbooks']

I want an output like

```
['E', 'Textbooks']
```

From the below code itself

```
nounbreak= [" ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])", i)) for i in listnew]
```

But somehow it is not happening. Don't know where I am going wrong. Would be great if anyone can help in this.

Comment: @JacobIRR thanks for your answer. But your solution does not take into account possibility of many words in a list. For e.g I have listnew=['E-Textbooks','gen-next','tri-pack'].  Here your above solution [0] references only first element. It has to be iterated over and there it become little inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `join` operation and use `itertools.chain` method in order to have a `flatten` list as desired result.

```
import re
import itertools
listnew = ['E-Textbooks', 'gen-next', 'tri-pack']
nounbreak = list(itertools.chain(*[re.findall(r"\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])", i) for i in listnew]))
```

Output

```
['E', 'Textbooks', 'gen', 'next', 'tri', 'pack']
```

Comment: I have a doubt. If I have a list as follows `['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management', '(', 'DCM', ')']`. The above solution does not seem to work. The output is as follows `['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management', '', 'DCM', '']`. I wonder why it is not giving the desired output `['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management']`. Request your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for your one example case:

```
nounbreak= [(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])", i)) for i in listnew]
```

> ['E', 'Textbooks']

If you have other, more complex input data, it would help to see that...

Comment: Yes, Ideally I have many words in this list. E.g                                                   listnew=['E-Textbooks', 'gen-next', 'tri-pack']. The reference of [0] just references first element. Could you please tell me how to solve if many other words are there like in the example I have cited here.

Comment: @venkatttaknev, for exemple you provided, what is the expected output ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut listnew=['E', 'Textbooks', 'gen', 'next', 'tri', 'pack']

Comment: @venkatttaknev, i updated my answer with a properly solution for this.

Comment: @venkatttaknev I removed the [0] at the end so now you have a list of lists

Comment: @JacobIRR yes , I noticed and upvoted your answer. Thank you.